# Moving data from s3 to redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a bucket in S3 and many folders inside that bucket. In each folder I have 5 to 6 files. I want to move these files to Redshift. I am using AWS crawler and Glue for moving the files. But, When I run the crawler only one table is being added to the data catalog. Any other ways to do this?
As an another option, I tried to iterate over files in the s3 folders without running crawlers. Instead, used jobs to connect to s3 directly. But, don't know how to move them to redshift.
this is the code where I am stuck.

```
client = boto3.client('glue',region_name='us-east-1')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
result = paginator.paginate(Bucket='bucketname',StartAfter='foldername')

for page in result:
    if "Contents" in page:
        for key in page[ "Contents" ]:
            keyString = key[ "Key" ]
            print keyString
```

Below is the code to move to redshift. Can anybody helping in change the codes in required way?

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options("s3",{'paths': ["file_paths"]},format="json")

datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = datasource0, catalog_connection = "redshift", connection_options = {"dbtable": , "database": "googlesheets"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/v2/workshops/9f29cdba-66c0-445e-8cbb-28a092cb5ba7/en-US)? You don't need glue after all, it is a convenience tool, which I found not very useful (for my use case)

Comment: Actually, we have uptodate data also. So glue is a part of data lake. that is why we are using Glue. And as we have large number of tables, we thought it would be better if we can automate these processes